# TYPO3 Solr: How to re index a file, which is linked in tt_content element in TYPO3

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a tt_content element in TYPO3 8.7, which contains a list of links to pdf files. Page and Files are indexed with ext:solr an ext:solrfal and I can find files by searching for contents of a pdf.

Now my question: How can I achieve, that a file will be reindexed by the planner task, when the content of that file is changed respectively when it is overwritten by a file with the same file name but different content. Do I need an additional TypoScript configuration for that?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are changed via the TYPO3 backend, then files should be detected and indexed.

Comment: OK. Did you check the documentation of ext:solrfal?

Comment: Referring to the docu of ext:solrfal I have done the following:

- Running planner tasks "File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index" frequently
- activate storageContext: 
    plugin.tx_solr.index.enableFileIndexing.storageContext = 1
- Merging Duplicates: 
    plugin.tx_solr.index.enableFileIndexing.mergeDuplicates = 1
    ...mergeDuplicates.fieldMapping.fileReferenceUrl = fileReferenceUrls_stringM

With this measures changes on files in file storage are recognized and will be reindexed on next run of the queue worker of ext:solrfal.

Oliver, is this what you suggested?